# Does pattern matched switch need to be always exhaustive in Java?

Tags: java, switch-statement, java-17, jep

[JEP 406](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/preview/specs/patterns-switch-jls.html) states:

> A pattern variable introduced by a *switch* label is definitely matched in the associated *switch* rule expression, *switch* rule block or *switch* rule throw statement.

Does this mean pattern matched switch needs to be compulsorily exhaustive regardless of whether it's used as a statement or an expression?

Comment: @user16320675 all possible cases, else with default

Comment: @user16320675 *definitely matched* implies exhaustiveness

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have asked two different questions. Your question’s title asks

> Does pattern matched switch need to be always exhaustive in java?

The answer is yes. This is given in [§14.11.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/preview/specs/patterns-switch-jls.html#jls-14.11.2):

> If the `switch` statement is an enhanced `switch` statement, then it must be exhaustive.

The definition of “enhanced switch statement” is given shortly before that statement

> An *enhanced* `switch` statement is one where either (i) the type of the selector expression is not `char`, `byte`, `short`, `int`, `Character`, `Byte`, `Short`, `Integer`, `String`, or an enum type, or (ii) at least one of the switch labels has a pattern case label element or a `null` case label element.

which implies that switch with pattern matching is always an enhanced switch statement.

---

But the body of your question is a different, very specific question:

> > A pattern variable introduced by a switch label is definitely matched in the associated
> > switch rule expression, switch rule block or switch rule throw statement.
>
> Does this mean pattern matched switch needs to be compulsorily exhaustive regardless of whether it's used as a statement or an expression?

The answer to this question is, no, this cited sentence does not have that meaning. The subject of this sentence is “pattern variable” and its scope is “the associated switch rule expression, switch rule block or switch rule throw statement”. So it’s not even remotely talking about the exhaustiveness of the entire `switch` statement.

When you have, e.g.

```java
   case Point p && p.x > 20 -> System.out.println("the right " + p);
```

The “pattern variable” is `p` and the part to the right of the `->` is “the associated switch rule expression” and the cited sentence says that within the latter, the variable `p` is “definitely matched”:

This is formally necessary for [§6.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.3-600) to establish that the variable will be in scope and initialized to the right of the `->` (or `:` if you’re still using it).

> The scope of a pattern variable declaration (that is, a local variable declared by a pattern) is the part of the program that might be executed after the matching of a value against the pattern has succeeded ([§14.30.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.30.2)). It is determined by considering the program points where the pattern variable is *definitely matched* in a region beginning with the pattern that declares the pattern variable.

Comment: thnx for cleaing that up...quoting from technical docs - thats not my forte...will refrain....14.11.2 answers it

Comment: The diff document is even harder to read, as it omits significant parts (because they haven’t changed), so I had to search a bit, to find out what “definitely matched” means or where it comes from.